# How to define API to query a related table before putting data

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I need some advice how to structure an API endpoint. I'm using Symfony 6.2 with API Plaform 3.1.

Let's say I have following 3 entities:

- User(id,...)
- APIKey(id, **userId**, apikey, ...)
- Log(id, **apikeyId**, ...)

So for each user there's an **APIKey**. Each **APIKey** can have several **Log** entries in a Log table.

Now I would like to set up 1 API endpoint which does the following tasks:

1. Check whether apikey exists --> Return an error code (404) if apikey doesn't exist
2. Receive log data. If there are more than 5 existing log entries re-use the oldest one. Otherwise create a new Log entry --> Return an ok code (200) when done

As you can see I need to do some business logic.

My idea is to setup a endpoint like that: `/api/log/{apikey}`
With the body tag I would send the log data

Now I'm not sure how to query the APIKey table for the `apikey` identifier. The API Platform project offers "**Relations**" and "**Extensions**". Is this the way to go or is the endpoint design not good at all?

Thanks for some advice in which direction I should do my recherche

Comment: Do you want to reuse the oldest log or remove it and add the new one ?

Comment: I want to reuse it (overwrite it with fresh data but keeping the primary key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two different implementations of this use case, but none of them use neither the Extension system or the Embedded relation system.

I have implemented this one, it makes you implements your own `ProcessorInterface` and passes to it a DTO.

First, let's declare a custom `PATCH` operation inside the `ApiKey` resource:

```php
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new GetCollection(),
        new Get(),
        new Post(),
        new Patch(),
        new Delete(),
        new Patch(
            uriTemplate: "/api_keys/{id}/log",
            normalizationContext: [
                "groups" => ["log:get:item-collection"],
            ],
            denormalizationContext: [
                "groups" => ["log:write"],
            ],
            input: Log::class,
            output: Log::class,
            processor: ApiKeyLogProcessor::class
        )
    ],
)]
class ApiKey {
    //...
    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'apiKey', targetEntity: Log::class, 
        cascade: ["persist", "remove"], orphanRemoval: true)
    ]
    private Collection $logs;
    
    //...
```

Then makes sure your `Log` resource has serialization groups `"log:write", "log:get:item-collection"` on property you need to deserialize/serialize:

```php
// src/Entity/Log.php

class Log {
    // ...
    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Groups(["log:get:item-collection", "log:post"])]
    private ?string $payload = null;
}
```

Then implements your `ProcessorInterface`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Processor;

use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Common\State\PersistProcessor;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Operation;
use ApiPlatform\State\ProcessorInterface;
use App\Entity\ApiKey;
use App\Repository\ApiKeyRepository;

class ApiKeyLogProcessor implements ProcessorInterface
{
    private ProcessorInterface $decorated;
    private ApiKeyRepository $doctrine;

    public function __construct(
        PersistProcessor $decorated,
        ApiKeyRepository $doctrine,
    )
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    public function process(mixed $data, Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = [])
    {
        $apiKey = $this->getApiKeyFromRequestContext($context);
        $apiKey = $this->removeOldestLogFromApiKeyIfNeeded($apiKey);
        $apiKey->addLog($data);
        return $this->decorated->process($data, $operation, $uriVariables, $context);
    }

    private function getApiKeyFromRequestContext(array $context): ?ApiKey
    {
        /** @var ApiKey $clonedApiKey */
        $clonedApiKey = $context["previous_data"];
        $apiKeyId = $clonedApiKey->getId();
        return $this->doctrine->find($apiKeyId);
    }

    private function removeOldestLogFromApiKeyIfNeeded(ApiKey $apiKey): ApiKey
    {
        $apiKeyLogsSet = $apiKey->getLogs();
        if ($apiKeyLogsSet->count() === 5) {
            $oldestLog = $apiKeyLogsSet[0]; // TODO: implements better logic to retrieve the oldest log.
            $apiKey->removeLog($oldestLog); // "orphanRemoval: true" will remove the oldest log from database
        }
        return $apiKey;
    }
}
```

Benefits of this custom route is that it always throw error 404 when `ApiKey` does not exist and always return success 200 on... success.

Another implementation is possible by declaring a custom `POST` operation on `Log` class and bind to it a `ProcessorInterface` to do the same job as the previous one. The body of the request will be :

```json
{ "payload": "my data...", "apiKey": "/api/api_keys/1" }
```

Benefit of this operation is that it retrieve the `ApiKey` resource without an additional call from `ApiKeyRepository`, but will throw an error 400 when `ApiKey` resource does not exist and always return success 201 on success.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable advice and example! I will try to implement this pattern. I will accept this answer as a solution as it looks quite good imho. I will let you know whether I could follow your steps.

Comment: The solution works! But one thing about your mentioned benefit. The API doesn't create a 404 if the ApiKey was not found. Instead it's a 500. I have to throw a NotFoundHttpException() in the Processor to return a 404. Is there a better way to produce this 404?

Comment: The custom PATCH operation is declared inside the `ApiKey` class, so like ANY other regular operation in this class, if the targeted ApiKey does not exist, API-Platform will return a 404 response. If it does not, you probably trigger another piece of code of your own somewhere else, but it is not related to the `Processor` implementation I gave you. The `Processor` is called at the `WriteListener` while the existence of the ApiKey is checked inside the `ReadListener`, so way before.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. So I have to double check why it's not triggered before the processor.